# How do I frame the SQLAlchemy URI for connecting the Database(8080) and Superset?

Tags: mysql, docker, port, apache-superset

Pulled MySQL image using command

```
docker pull mysql
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

Then made a stack.yml file in my root for mysql

```
stack.yml :
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And lastly composed it up.

```
docker-compose -f stack.yml up (after making the stack.yml file)
```

After it stopped running I accessed the localhost:8080 page and the mysql database login page was loaded.

Superset setup

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset.git
cd incubator-superset
docker-compose up
```

Accessed superset on localhost:8088 page.

How do I frame the SQLAlchemy URI for connecting the Database and Superset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access both applications individually due to it has a different bridge network. But when it comes to connecting each other, You have to connect through the same network for both applications. Superset already running on **incubator-superset_default** and MySQL running on **default bridge** network.

Here tested stack.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: sample
    networks:
      - proxynet

networks:
   proxynet:
      name: incubator-superset_default
```

Note:
As a user-defined network so use can use the service container name or container IP address as follows

> ```
> mysql://root:sample@mysql/mysql
> mysql://root:sample@172.19.0.5/mysql
> ```